# Uncaught TypeError: $(...) is not a function while using morris.js chart

Tags: jquery, morris.js

I'm using morris chart on my webpage and I'm keep getting the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...) is not a function
```

It's also visible in the console when you enter this page with morris charts - http://jqueryajaxphp.com/preview/charts/ what is wrong here?

Comment: try jQuery at the place of $

Comment: Didn't do the trick there too :/

Comment: that url is the most terrifying link I've never clicked.

Comment: I currently have `$(function (jQuery, window) {` at the beginning of the file and `})(jQuery, window);` at the end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up two different jQuery patterns.

This:

```
$(function($) { });
```

… will call a function when the ready state hits.

This:

```
(function ($, window, undefined) {

})(jQuery, window);
```

… will trap your variables in a closure and increase the chances that `$`, `window` and `undefined` have the right value.

You are doing this:

```
$(function ($, window, undefined) {

})(jQuery, window);
```

… which tries to call the return value of `$()` as if it was a function, which it isn't.

To combine the two patterns you would do this:

```
(function ($, window, undefined) {
    $(function($) { 

    });
})(jQuery, window);
```

That said, it is more typical to just trust that `window` and `undefined` aren't going to be messed around with and do this:

```
jQuery(function($) { 

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually this error is thrown when JQuery is still not initialized...

Check your code that JQuery is the first one loaded... something like:

```
<!-- First of all jquery... -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- ... Then all the javascripts you need --> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="yourScript.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks, but that's not the case here, jquery is called in a header of the file and scripts are called later on...